# General solution of $X' = ((0,0),(0,0))X$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So usually we use the $\det(A-\lambda I)$ to get eigenvalues to get eigenvectors to solve for a general solution.  This seems neither necessary nor helpful here, just wondering if the general solution is just $(c_1, c_2) = X$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants in complex numbers, since the derivative matrix is always 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the matrix-vector multiplication:
$$X'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{matrix}\right)X(t)$$
$$X'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1'(t)\\
x_2'(t)
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$
So your equations are:
$$x_1'(t)=0$$
$$x_2'(t)=0$$
And I think you can solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$
\int_0^t X'(\tau)d\tau = X(t)-X(0)
$$

but due to your equation:

$$
\int_0^t X'(\tau)d\tau = \int_0^t \left(\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{matrix}\right) X(\tau)d\tau = \left(\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{matrix}\right) \int_0^t X(\tau)d\tau = \left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Hence $X(t)$ is a constant.